How does one clear a rectangle being drawn at mouse coordinates in javascript?
I'm trying to draw a rectangle at the mouse's coordinates however I haven't been able to get it to clear without clearing the other objects.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
     html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  canvas {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background: black;
  }
  </style>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<canvas width="1250" height="600" id="game">
    <script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;

function loop(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  let levelMax = 5;
  let box = [];
  for (j=0;j<levelMax;j++){
    for (i=0;i<levelMax;i++){
          ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
        box.push({
          X : (75 * i),
          Y : 525 - (j*75),
          Width : 75,
          Height : 75
        });
        ctx.fillRect(box[(j*levelMax)+i].X, box[((j*levelMax)+i)].Y, box[i].Width, box[i].Height);
}
}
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
  let posX = e.offsetX;
  let posY = e.offsetY;
  ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 50, 50);
});
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    </script></canvas>
  </body>
</html>

I tried to use ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); which didn't clear the mouse's squares or cleared the other squares but cleared old squares from the mouse as desired. I also tried to use 'ctx.clearRect(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 50, 50);' which never really worked, either clearing the squares before they showed up and clearing the larger boxes if the mouse went over them, or just never cleared the mouse's box.

Call ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); in your mousemove event, first line should do the trick.

The main problem is that the mousemove event listener is placed inside the loop() function


<canvas width="1250" height="600" id="game"></canvas>
    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      let mouseX = 0;
      let mouseY = 0;

      function loop() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const levelMax = 5;
        const box = [];
        
        for (let j = 0; j < levelMax; j++) {
          for (let i = 0; i < levelMax; i++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
            box.push({
              X: (75 * i),
              Y: 525 - (j * 75),
              Width: 75,
              Height: 75
            });
            ctx.fillRect(box[(j * levelMax) + i].X, box[(j * levelMax) + i].Y, box[i].Width, box[i].Height);
          }
        }

        ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      }

      window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseX = e.clientX - rect.left;
        mouseY = e.clientY - rect.top;
      });

      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    </script>



